# Android Facebook ShareDialog.show method returning FacebookDialogException

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on FaceBook SDK version 4.5.0, able to share content using ShareApi if FACEBOOK is installed, if FACEBOOK is not installed using shareDialog.show(linkContent).

But app is getting crashed. Please let me know any one facing same problem and share your thoughts.

> **Error:** {FacebookDialogException: errorCode: -2, message: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, url:
>   https://m.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/feed?description=The%20%27Hello%20Facebook%27%20sample%20%20showcases%20simple%20Facebook%20integration&app_id=1643854509221514&sdk=android-4.5.0&name=Hello%20Facebook&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch}

```
private void postStatusUpdate() {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new                  ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android")).setContentUrl(Uri.parse(""))
                .build();
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        } else if (profile != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you should first check that the **Facebook App is installed or not**.

If it's installed then you can called your code but if it's not then you can do the following.

```
    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + linkString;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

For checking you can use below code :

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
                                         FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am working on  FB SDK v4.5.0.